# How does the distribution of Math.random()*50 + Math.random()*20 compare to Math.random()*70?

Tags: javascript, random, statistics

How does the distribution of:

```
var randomNumber = Math.random()*50 + Math.random()*20;
```

compare to that of:

```
var randomNumber = Math.random()*70;
```

Comment: I think you'll get a better answer in stat.stackexchange.com, as it only depends on mathematical properties and not on any specific language. Try asking "linear uniform distribution" * A + "linear uniform distribution" * B = "linear uniform distribution" * (A + B)

Comment: Equal. a*(b+c)=a*b+a*c after Adam Riese

Comment: @Jonasw That's incorrect. The distribution of a sum of random variables is the convolution of their density functions, so it is generally different.

Comment: [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) is applicable in this case. The sum of two distributions will get closer to the standard distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first will not produce a flat distribution with more values near 70/2, while the second will produce an even distribution..

The easy way to find out is just to sample the values and graph them.

Sampled slowly just for fun.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const a1 = new Float64Array(70);
const a2 = new Float64Array(70);
var total = 0;
function doSamples(samples){
    for(var i = 0; i < samples; i ++){
        var n1 = Math.random() * 50 + Math.random() * 20;
        var n2 = Math.random() * 70;
        a1[n1 | 0] += 1;
        a2[n2 | 0] += 1;
    }
    var max = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 70; i ++){
        max = Math.max(max,a1[i],a2[i]);
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for(i = 0; i < 70; i ++){
        var l1 = (a1[i] / max) * canvas.height;
        var l2 = (a2[i] / max) * canvas.height;
        ctx.fillStyle = "Blue";
        ctx.fillRect(i * 8,canvas.height - l1,4,l1)
        ctx.fillStyle = "Orange";
        ctx.fillRect(i * 8 + 4,canvas.height - l2,4,l2)
        
    }
    total += samples;
    count.textContent = total;
}
function doit(){
    doSamples(500);
    setTimeout(doit,100);
}
doit();
```

```css
canvas {border:2px solid black;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width = 560 height =  200></canvas><br>
Orange is random() * 70<br>
Blue is random() * 50 + random() * 20<br>
Graph is normalised.
<span id="count"></span> samples.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do a brute force approach by counting a million random values and check if the sum `r70s` is equal to a single random value `r70`.

As you see the distribution is not equal.

```js
function countValue(key, value) {
    value = Math.floor(value);
    count[key][value] = (count[key][value] || 0) + 1;
}

var i,
    r20, r50, r70,
    count = { r20: [], r50: [], r70: [], r70s: [] };
    
for (i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    r20 = Math.random() * 20;
    r50 = Math.random() * 50;
    r70 = Math.random() * 70;
    countValue('r20', r20);
    countValue('r50', r50);
    countValue('r70', r70);
    countValue('r70s', r20 + r50);
}

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The density function of a sum of random variables is the convolution of the density functions of the summands.

In this case the two summands have uniform densities, therefore their convolution is a piecewise linear function (a triangle). In general for the sum of n uniform variables, the density of the sum is a piecewise polynomial of degree n - 1.

The sum has the expected value equal to the sum of the expected values, namely 50/2 and 20/2, which is equal to 70/2, which is the expected value of Math.random()*70. So the expected values are the same, but the distributions are different.